# Visifire MVVM: Is it possible to have visifire chart's data series collection property in view model?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm

I have created a silverlight 4 application and using visifire charting components.

I am using MVVM pattern and have created a view which contains:

```
<Charts:Chart x:Name="myChart">
```

The issue is that the number of data series of the chart will change.

I have got all of the logic in place now and is working if I don't use MVVM model and directly set the myChart's series property.

Now, I want to set the data series collection of the chart in my view model.

I have created a DataSeriesCollection property in view model.

If I was setting data series collection in my backend code (if I was not using MVVM), I would do simply:

```
this.myChart.Series = MyDataSeriesCollection;
```

where MyDataSeriesCollection is a collection of DataSeries

but I don't know how I need to set the binding of DataSeriesCollection in the xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at Sep 2010 it looks like the DataSeries property is not bindable:

See this forum post, aswered by Visifire: [Databinding Series property?](http://www.visifire.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=2169)

It may that Visifire is a few steps behind the latest trends towards MVVM and binding *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem as @InfoLearner and I believe that I know how I might address this issue so that I'll be able to dynamically add more `DataSeries` objects to my visifire chart using binding.

My idea is to create a `UserControl` that holds the Visifire chart within it (only the chart), then, I'll add some dependency properties with the stuff I want to be able to bind to (like `DataSeriesCollection` property, Styles etc.) and then I'll hook it up to my chart in the control's code behind. I believe it's the only viable solution until Visifire would be kind enough to provide their controls with properly bindable properties.

HTH.